# how to re-size the image flyer link in css

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have the image link which displayed on personal website.I am  trying to re-size the image by creating css style sheets on this image since i was copy the code direct and paste to the page and i need to displayproperly on mobile devices

code

```
     <div id="TA_selfserveprop634" class="TA_selfserveprop">
     <ul id="FkGjsTFbWr" class="TA_links aICFqBWnArX">
     <li id="v65BTuNt" class="Id2gL5m3F1"><a target="_blank" href=     "https://www.tripadvisor.com/"><img src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/150_logo-11900-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"/></a>
  </li></ul></div>
  <script src="https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&amp;uniq=634&amp;locationId=307103&amp;lang=en_US&amp;rating=true&amp;nreviews=5&amp;writereviewlink=true&amp;popIdx=true&amp;iswide=false&amp;border=true&amp;display_version=2"></script>                 
                </div>
               </div>
```

CSS

```
    .TA_selfserveprop{
        width:10%;
        height:10%;
    }

    .TA_links aICFqBWnArX{

        width:10%;
        height:10%;
    }

    .Id2gL5m3F1{

        width:10%;
        height:10%;
    }
```

When refresh my page this CSS styles does not have any effects on image..

Can anyone let me know on how to rearrange the coding style so that the Size of the image displayed properly on my website.

Comment: It's not `image` it's a `div` , take a look at [This](https://jsfiddle.net/odteg447/)

Comment: Width seems working fine but the height doesn't work.

Comment: Height is the most important to me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a `div` responsive and `full screen` at any device, you should use `width: 100%` and height: `100%`.

```css
#CDSWIDSSP {
  width: 100%!important;
  height: 100%!important;
}
.TA_selfserveprop {
  width: 100%!important;
  height: 100%!important;
}
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#CDSWIDSSP .widSSPData {
  height: 100%;
}

#CDSWIDSSP .widSSPData {
overflow: auto!important
}
```

```html
<div id="TA_selfserveprop634" class="TA_selfserveprop">
  <ul id="FkGjsTFbWr" class="TA_links aICFqBWnArX">
    <li id="v65BTuNt" class="Id2gL5m3F1">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/">
        <img src="https://www.tripadvisor.com/img/cdsi/img2/branding/150_logo-11900-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&amp;uniq=634&amp;locationId=307103&amp;lang=en_US&amp;rating=true&amp;nreviews=5&amp;writereviewlink=true&amp;popIdx=true&amp;iswide=false&amp;border=true&amp;display_version=2"></script>
</div>
</div>
```

please note that for `height: 100%` you need to set this for `body` and `html`.

Comment: can we resize the height?..seems height is not resizing i need to make it small in size

Comment: @Vadz updated. you need to set `overflow: auto` because default one is hidden.

Comment: do i have to create a new class with the example showed above?#CDSWIDSSP and  #widSSPData

Comment: @Vadz just copy mine codes, no need to create new class.